# Xcode Error Cant CopyPNG

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can't find users/users/vikrantmisra/downloads etc , this project was made by co-employe now I am working on it as I imported this project so can anyone help me how to solve this error

[image]

Comment: Since I can't see any code here, I can only assume that the path has been hardcoded. Or if it's not then delete the Derived Data folder, Clean the project and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error come when `Xcode` contain image path but at that place image not exist because when developer use that image he/she direct drag and drop image to Xcode and does not use copy check mark about do you wish just give that image **reference  or copy items if needed** and at that time your dev's did not check copy items if needed and its image just adding as its reference.

So while you change location of project or system that path can not exist at `Xcode` side. You can fix it by following steps:

1. search image name from bottom search bar left panel of xcode.
2. You can see that madical_31.png in red color.
3. remove that image and add that image again by right click--> add files to.

You issue must be fix by followed that steps.